# Issue with my Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple problem of entering price for orange and the number of oranges to buy and calculating the total cost.
Please check this code and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
var numberofOranges;
var costofOrange;
var orangeCost = function (costofOrange, numberofOranges) {
    var Cost = costofOrange * numberofOranges;
    return Cost;
};
confirm ("Confirm Number of Oranges you are buying", numberofOranges, costofOrange);
if ((numberofOranges === > 0 && typeof(numberofOranges)!= "string") && (costofOranges === > 0 && typeof(costofOranges)!= "string")) {
console.log("Cost of" + numberofOranges + "Oranges is" + (orangeCost(numberofOranges));

}
else {
console.log("Enter valid input");
}
```

Comment: Log out the variables with `console.log(variable)` and find out for yourself.

Comment: For starters, that's not how `confirm()` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: everything below the orangeCost function is totaly wrong. confirm is not suposed to work like this and "=== >" this is not a thing, orangeCost is used with one parameter but you need 2 of them and you need to use it like this orangeCost(5,20); - 5 dollars and 20 oranges. Also guys stop with the down vote, it obvious that he tried this is not copy paste from google!

Comment: sorry I made a mistake of using confirm instead of prompt for user to enter the values.. Also I am a beginner in learning javascript and has no prior experience. Thanks for the patience and help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
(function () {
    var numberofOranges;
    var costofOrange;
    var orangeCost = function (costofOrange, numberofOranges) {
        var Cost = costofOrange * numberofOranges;
        return Cost;
    };
    numberofOranges = Number(prompt("Confirm Number of Oranges you are buying"));
    costofOrange = Number(prompt("Confirm Cost of Oranges"));
    console.log(costofOrange + " : " + numberofOranges);

    if (( !isNaN(numberofOranges) && numberofOranges >= 0) && ( !isNaN(costofOrange) && costofOrange >= 0)) {
        console.log("Cost of" + numberofOranges + " Oranges is " + orangeCost(costofOrange, numberofOranges) );
    }
    else {
    console.log("Enter valid input");
    }
})();
```

Couple of things to keep in mind,

- window.prompt() is used to take input, better way would be to use some  tag
- prompt() returns a value and it's always string, we have to convert this this value to number or to the required format.
- isNaN() is just checking if the value received from the prompt() after conversion to number is number or not. NaN stands for Not a Number. An NaN value can not be checked by ordinary means. Even NaN === NaN will return false, only way to check if a value is NaN use isNaN() function
- numberofOranges and costOrange variables are already available to the orangeCost() function. If you do need these as parameters, good practice would be to make rename them as something else, ie. paramNumberofOranges, so that parameters do not shadow the outer variables.